# r - run a user defined function several times by taking column elements as parameters

Tags: r, switch-statement, apply, do.call

When x[1,1]=net2013 , I get the output as 20.  But what do I have to do to execute this piece of code for all the elements of the first column of x (i.e: x[ ,1]).  While loop didn't execute and I'm having trouble with apply and do.call.  I have to use a switch statement and obtain output for tens of thousands of rows.  Please help.

```
> z=10
> centre <- function(z,type){
+      switch(as.character(type),            
+             net2014=star2014(z), 
+             net2013=star2013(z))
+ }
> star2014 <- function(z)
+ {
+      z*5
+ }
> star2013 <- function(z)
+ {
+      z*2
+ }
> centre(z,x[1,1])
[1] 20
> centre(z,x[14,1])
[1] 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you need is probably

```
  lapply(x[, 1], function(A) centre(z, A))
```

Here, `x[, 1]` is the entire 1st column of `x`. lapply iterates over its elements one at a time, applying the function `centre`.

If you want a simplified result, replace `lapply` with `sapply`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm still learning R.  Your answer helped me immensely.